# Changing color of toggle arrows, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: Table]

I am currently sorting a table and I would like arrows to indicate which column is being sorted. I am able to sort with arrows now, but would like to change the color of the arrow in the row that is being currently sorted. How can I accomplish this?

Here is the code I am using:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hw7ebgym/)

```js
$(function() {
  $("th.pc").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
    var rows = $(".dental_table tbody tr").get();
    rows.sort(sortTable);
    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
      $(".dental_table").children("tbody").append(row);
    });
    if (ascending) {
      ascending = false;
    } else {
      ascending = true;
    }
  });
});

var ascending = false;

function sortTable(a, b) {
  var A = parseInt($(a).children('td').eq(0).text().replace(/[^\d.]/g, ""), 10);
  var B = parseInt($(b).children('td').eq(0).text().replace(/[^\d.]/g, ""), 10);

  if (ascending) {
    if (A > B) return 1;
    if (A < B) return -1;
  } else {
    if (A > B) return -1;
    if (A < B) return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="dental_table table">
    <thead id="thead">
      <tr>
        <th class="pc">Unit Price</th>
        <th id="st_id">SKU</th>
        <th id="st_name">Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
      <tr>
        <td>$3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Dental Product 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Dental #2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$5</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Pharma 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Oral 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>$4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Dental 5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and CSS code in your snippet. Currently, you only have posted JavaScript.

Comment: added html to question

Comment: I have revised your question to embed jQuery and combined the HTML and JavaScript into one post. I don't see any arrows in the output. Can you verify that all of your code is in the snippet?

Comment: please check the code link for jsfiddle. I don't know why it is not compiling on here.

Comment: Does my answer help clarify?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I was actually looking for a way in which each column was sortable and then the column that was currently being sorted had a different color than the other columns.

Comment: Okay, as this is a different topic than the color of the arrows, can you post a new question with a title of changing the color of the columns based on what is sorted? Then, please post the link here and I will take a look.

Comment: I cannot post again for 90 minutes.

Comment: Got it. In the meantime, as my answer resolves the first question, would you be able to mark it with the green checkbox (and upvote if you find my responses helpful), then when you are allowed to post again, post the new question?

Comment: sure. Is there anyway you can help me now with my question?

Comment: I never saw that you posted your second question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the color of the arrow (which is defined as a character in `CSS`, you must change the `color` attribute as done here (where up is `blue` and down is `red`).

```js
$(function(){
 $("th.pc").on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("down");
        var rows = $(".dental_table tbody tr").get();
        rows.sort(sortTable);
        $.each(rows, function(index, row){
                $(".dental_table").children("tbody").append(row);
        });
      if (ascending) {
       ascending = false; 
      } else {
       ascending = true; 
      }
    });
});

var ascending = false;

function sortTable(a,b){
    var A = parseInt($(a).children('td').eq(0).text().replace(/[^\d.]/g,""), 10);
    var B = parseInt($(b).children('td').eq(0).text().replace(/[^\d.]/g,""), 10);


  if (ascending) {
    if (A > B) return 1;
    if( A < B) return -1;
  } else {
    if (A > B) return -1;
    if( A < B) return 1;
  }
    return 0;

}
```

```css
thead{background-color:lightblue}
thead tr th{cursor:pointer}
thead tr th:hover{background-color:#cccccc}
th.pc:after{
  content: "\25B2";
  color: blue;
}
th.pc.down:after{
  content: "\25BC";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">       </script>
 <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="dental_table table">
            <thead id="thead">
                <tr>
                    <th class="pc">Unit Price</th>
                    <th id="st_id">SKU</th>
                    <th id="st_name">Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">
                <tr>
                    <td>$3</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Dental Product 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$2</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Dental #2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$5</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>Pharma 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$1</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>Oral 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>$4</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Dental 5</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified CSS:

```
thead{background-color:lightblue}
thead tr th{cursor:pointer}
thead tr th:hover{background-color:#cccccc}
th.pc:after{
  content: "\25B2";
}
th.pc.down:after{
  content: "\25BC";
}
.custom-up:after {
    content: "\25B2";
    color: green;
}

.custom-down:after {
   content: "\25BC"; 
   color: blue;
}
```

Modified JS:

```
$(function(){
 $("th.pc").on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass("down");
        var rows = $(".dental_table tbody tr").get();
        rows.sort(sortTable);
        $.each(rows, function(index, row){
                $(".dental_table").children("tbody").append(row);
        });
      if (ascending) {
       ascending = false; 
       $(this).addClass('custom-down');
       $(this).removeClass('custom-up');
      } else {
       $(this).addClass('custom-up');
       $(this).removeClass('custom-down');
       ascending = true; 
      }
    });
});

var ascending = false;

function sortTable(a,b){
    var A = parseInt($(a).children('td').eq(0).text().replace(/[^\d.]/g,""), 10);
    var B = parseInt($(b).children('td').eq(0).text().replace(/[^\d.]/g,""), 10);


  if (ascending) {
    if (A > B) return 1;
    if( A < B) return -1;
  } else {
    if (A > B) return -1;
    if( A < B) return 1;
  }
    return 0;

}
```

Basically we overwrite the class in CSS and add it at the toggle action; you can mess with the colors and play around with it; hope it helps.